# Black checkboxes on IOS browsers

Tags: html, ios, css, less

I'm having trouble fixing one issue with checkbox on IOS browsers. I always get a black check icon with a black square around it (picture). This only happens on IOS browsers.

I'm using

```
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
```

Any ideas?
Anyone had the same problem?

[image]

Comment: Please share your code (HTML, CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several ways to fix it, but in the end I tried one simple thing and it worked... I change the SVG that I was using. Just added white background on the SVG image and it worked!

Thanks for the help anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, since I can't access and play with your code, but try doing:

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Might work, idk. If not, some source code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Setting background-color to transparent solved this for me.